# Understanding Perl match and index functions

Tags: perl

I've inherited the following Perl code, and I'm having difficulty understanding what exactly the index and match functions are doing here:

```
my $url = $ENV{'REQUEST_URI'};
my $loc = $url;
$loc =~ s/\/parks\///i;
my $page = substr($loc, 0, index $loc, "_");
```

I know that index(str, char) returns the index of a particular character, so what function does `index $loc` serve? Is it simply returning the length?

I'm also confused by the line `$loc =~ s/\/parks\///i;` which matches the phrase "/parks/" in the url. I don't see the purpose of it, because whether it returns `true` or `false`, isn't $loc still a string containing the url? What should I expect to be contained in $page?

I am very new to Perl so I appreciate that there will be some nuances that I haven't yet grasped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl's slightly cavalier approach to parenthesis might be confusing you a little here. The calls to `substr` and `index` might be more clearly written as:

```
my $page = substr($loc, 0, index($loc, "_"));
```

It's looking for the first occurrence of '_' in $loc and truncating the variable at that point.

Also, the substitution operator would be easier to understand if you used alternative delimiters.

```
$loc =~ s|/parks/||i;
```

It means "look for the first occurrence of "/parks/" in $loc and replace it with an empty string (i.e. remove it).

Answer (score 1):

```
$loc =~ s/\/parks\///i;
```

This will remove `/parks/` from the string $loc

```
my $page = substr($loc, 0, index $loc, "_");
```

can be written as:

```
# retrieve the position of the first "_" in the string $loc 
my $index = index $loc, "_";
# keep the begining of the string from position 0 to position $index
my $page = substr($loc, 0, $index);
```

Comment: Not quite. $index becomes the length argument in substr, so you get everything up to the character before the first "_"